# How do I center this horizontal list within a fixed div?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a UL element containing 4 icons within a div that is using absolute positioning to pull it to the bottom of the screen. That div is contained within a fixed sidebar.

I have used `display: inline` on the list items to give me a horizontal list.

Here is my code running on bootply to demonstrate the problem I'm having. The 4 icons are offset to the right slightly when they should be central:

http://bootply.com/76539

Other content put in the sidebar has no issues with being central. It's just this list.

I have tried quite a lot of methods of trying to get the icons central within the sidebar and none of them seem to be working. I have tried `inline-block` and `float:left` on the list items and seem to be getting the same result.

Can anyone see the mistake here? I'm sure there's something simple I've missed.

Comment: I never knew about Bootply.com, looks very useful, thanks for the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#social-icons ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

Also you wrote `text-align: c` instead of `text-align: center`

I also edited your example: [link](http://bootply.com/76545)

Comment: Ah yeah, that was just a mistake when I copied it over. I knew it would be something a simple as margin and padding though. I was just relying too much on Chrome's developer tools telling me that there wasn't any margin or padding. Thank you for your help. I'm sure I would have been here staring at it for a while longer otherwise.